# Performance issues when populating datagrid during deserialization

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, xaml, serialization

Our datagrid is roughly 50 rows and 30 columns. All columns are templatecolumns with a custom cellstyle and we are using materialdesign styling. Most columns have the same template as the one below but with bindings to different properties.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>    
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="60" Text="Time-Column"/>
           </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <Border 
                       BorderThickness="0,0,0,0"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       CornerRadius="3"
                       MinHeight="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path=TestHeight}>
                                                   
               <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="3*"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Ellipse Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                             Margin="2,1,0,0" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="{Binding 
                       TimeCell.IsChangedVisibility,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                       Width="5"  
                       Height="5"  
                       Fill="Cyan"  
                       Panel.ZIndex="100"/>

                  <TextBox Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTextBox}" 
                    GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" TabIndex="0" 
                    MinHeight="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path=TestRow}" 
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" Width="65"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" 
                    SelectionChanged="TextBox_SelectionChanged"  
                    Text="{Binding TimeCell.DisplayText2, 
                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}">
                  </TextBox>

                  <Label IsHitTestVisible="False" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="10" Content="{Binding TimeCell.Unit, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"></Label>
                 
                  <TextBlock Focusable="False" Text="{Binding TimeCell.CellBadge.Text, 
                   Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,TargetNullValue=''}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"  FontSize="9" FontWeight="SemiBold" 
                   Foreground="#db4848" Margin="0,-1,2,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                   Grid.Row="0" IsHitTestVisible="False">
                  </TextBlock>

             </Grid>

             </Border>

        </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

[image: TemplateColumnCellTemplate Result]

When starting the program the datagrid takes roughly 4-5 seconds to load. When attempting to load another file / collection and setting datacontext it takes roughly 4-5 seconds again and a 50 MB ram increase per load.
I have tried reducing the amount of columns and everything becomes a bit faster but the delay and RAM increase (of 20mb instead of 50mb) are still there. Row and Column virtualization are enabled.

We use BinaryFormatter as our serializer / deserializer.

How can we get a smooth and lag-free layout when populating and on load / startup?

Comment: Have you tried to profile your app? What methods cause the lag?

Comment: I suggest you try separating the steps and put a stopwatch on each. Show your window. Get your data. Present it to the datagrid. Measure and arrange can be quite expensive. Try setting the column width to a fixed number and see what effect that has. And why is it another 50 meg per load?  Binary serialisation is usually to be avoided ime. You can't just add a column later.

Comment: No method in particular seems to cause any lag, rather it's the layout. Not really sure what that means for us. Should we hardcode the sizes more? Or size them by percents?

Andy, thank you, will do. As I have already written, layout seems to be the culprit. I have no idea as to why it's another 50 mb per load, that's what we're trying to figure out. Another method of serialization is another good idea.

Comment: You need a lot of data before binary serialisation is worth the downsides. First choice should always be to string. Way more flexible. There are arguments for xml or json. Looking at your template. Make it fixed height and width. If you do that then there is only one measure arrange pass per cell. Otherwise there are many more. Maybe number of cells squared. Each says I want n width as it's loaded. The layout then says... what else do I have. What do you want col 2... hmmm... how about col 3... hmmm.. col 4?  and so on. Then the next row. Oh... this one' in column3 is wider...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can possibly do so, it is best to have fixed widths and heights for all columns and rows. This can be in * measures or in some other measure like px. So long as it's not auto.

If you instead have auto sizing then all cells demand their width ( and maybe height ) then the size each in a column demands must be taken into account before the container knows how wide any given column will be. This can add up to a substantial overhead.

Auto height on rows with a template whose height may vary will similarly give a lot of layout calculations per row.

Another great way to slow things down is if your columns don't all fit.  The control then has to decide where that cut off point is. This is likely to make a datagrid scroll really slow.

If you want to speed things up.

Consider a listview. They're inherently simpler than a datagrid.

Reduce that measure arrange cycling down by calculating absolute widths or using proportional (* based) widths and heights.